# Does the LG K7 have IR capabilities?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

Does the LG K7 have IR capabilities?

If it does, is there a way I could use it as a remote control?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody ever Googles before asking these days? [PDAdb](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=9566&c=lg_k330_k_series_k7_lte_lg_m1)

> Infrared Gate: Not supported

End of question.